Diffeomorphisms that let the Haar measure invariant and null divergent
Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Haar measure $\mu$. Let $X\in\mathfrak{X} (G)$ be such that, if $T(x)=\exp_x(X_x)$,
$$T_*\mu=\mu,$$
then $\operatorname{div}(X)=0$?
This is true when $G=S^1$, because the diffeomorfisms that let the Lebesgue measure on $S^1$ invariant are the rigid rotations and the rigid reflections, thus, such an $X$ should be constant, hence without divergence.
I'm trying this line of reasoning: if we let $T_t(x)=\exp_x(tX_x)$, and consider de Jacobian $J_t(x)$ given by
$$(T_t)_*\mu=J_t(x)\mu$$
Be derivating at $t=0$ we get
$$\dot{J_0}(x)=-\operatorname{div}(X)(x).$$
Since $T_0(x)=x$, we have that, by integrating,
$$J_t(x)=e^{-\int_0^t\operatorname{div}(X)(T_s(x)) ds}.$$
Since $(T_1)_*\mu=\mu$, $J_1\equiv 1$ and thus,
\begin{equation}\label{integraljacobiano}
    \int_0^1\operatorname{div}(X)(T_s(x)) ds=0,
\end{equation}
for every $x\in G$.
But I cannot go any further.

What's the meaning of ${\exp}_x$? The Lie exponential map is defined as a map $\exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$.

@RamiroLafuente Riemannian exponential

But then you need to specify a Riemannian metric.
